# File not found error comes when trying to run pvk2pfx.exe file

Tags: authentication, iis-7, x509certificate, client-certificates, makecert

I am trying to create simple client side certificate and for that I following below link...

How to create client certificate

I have installed SDK on machine, and I have successfully run below two commands.

```
makecert.exe -r -n "CN=My Personal CA" -pe -sv MyPersonalCA.pvk -a sha1 -len 2048 -b 01/21/2010 -e 01/21/2016 -cy authority MyPersonalCA.cer


makecert.exe -iv MyPersonalCA.pvk -ic MyPersonalCA.cer -n "CN=John Doe" -pe -sv JohnDoe.pvk -a sha1 -len 2048 -b 01/21/2010 -e 01/21/2016 -sky exchange JohnDoe.cer -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2
```

After running these two commands successfully , When I try to run the third command I get the error "File Not Found" (Error Code = 0x80070002).

Third command is

```
pvk2pfx.exe -pvk JohnDoe.pvk -spc JohnDoe.cer -pfx JohnDoe.pfx -po password
```

Whats the issue?